# Send and receive data through infrared (IR) between 2 mBots (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, infrared

I have two mBots (Arduino robots) and I would like to know how to comunicate both with the infrared sensors of the Board. The maximum I have achieved is to detect in the mBot a button pulse off the remote control. What I would really like to do is to send ints from the first mBot to the second, but it looks like the mBot infrared code is only thinked for detecting the remote control buttons pulses. If I could just send from the first mBot the same pulse that sends the remote control when you press a button to the second mBot, then I could do a switch case and convert the received button pulse (button 0 for instance) to a number (int received = 0).

Instead of doing so, it would be better to directly send and receive ints or even strings. But at this point any way to comunicate the two mBots with the infrared would be fine to me.

This is the code i have for detecting the button pulse of the remote control in the mBot:

```
include Wire.h 
include SoftwareSerial.h 
include MeMCore.h

MeIR ir;
MeBuzzer buzzer;

void setup()
{

ir.begin();

}

void loop(){

if(ir.keyPressed(22)) // receive button 0 pulse
buzzer.tone(460,200); // make a beep 
}
```

¿Does someone know how it will be the code for sending and receiving data between the two mBots? (even if its only the pulses for the button numbers from 0 to 9)

Please bear in mind that because these robots are not exactly arduino uno boards, the normal arduino way to use the IR sensors won't work since mBot has its own build up and own libraries.

Any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

How to comunicate two mBots via infrared:

1: Download the Arduino-IRremote library: https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote

2: Go to C/programs/Arduino/libraries and erase the default IR library, since its not the same that this one and it causes incompatibilities. Then copy the Arduino-IRremote library folder to add it to the Arduino libraries.

3: Open the makeblock library and in the file MeMCore.h comment the line 68 (//#include "MeIR.h"). This is also to avoid incompatibilities.

Finally you are able to upload to your mBot the sketches to send and receive data via infrarred. This are the codes to send and receive data:

Send data via IR:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

IRsend irsend;

int robot_ori=91;
int n_coordenadas=4;
int x[10], y[10];

void setup()
{
  x[1]=200;   y[1]=217;
  x[2]=199;   y[2]=213;
  x[3]=210;   y[3]=179;
  x[4]=212;   y[4]=140;
}

void loop() 
{

  irsend.sendSony(robot_ori, 16);   // data to send, nº of bits to send 
  delay(40);                        // for int type is 16 bits
  irsend.sendSony(n_coordenadas, 16); 
  delay(40);

  for (int i = 1; i <= n_coordenadas; i++) 
  {
    irsend.sendSony(x[i], 16);
    delay(40);  
    irsend.sendSony(y[i], 16);        
    delay(40);
  }

  delay(5000); //5 second delay between each signal burst

}
```

Receive data via IR:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 2;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);

decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, DEC); // DEC decimal, HEX hexadecimal, etc
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```